# Delete multiple columns from all text files in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a folder with hundreds of .txt files that each have the same 14 column headings on the first row. The values are space separated, and I am trying to remove multiple of the columns from each of these files at once.

I have tried multiple times to do this using glob and pandas as seen below, but get stuck trying to read all of the files in the folder into a dataframe.

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd

folder_path = 'Desktop/GRB/data/k1/'
file_list = glob.glob(folder_path + "/\*.txt")
main_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(pd.readcsv(file_list\[0\], delimiter=r"\\s+"))
for i in range (1,len(file_list)):
    data = pd.read_csv(file_list\[i\], delimiter=r"\\s+")
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    main_dataframe = pd.concat(\[main_dataframe,df\],axis=1)
print(main_dataframe)
```

I am new to using pandas and don't know how to do this successfully.
I also plan to use df = df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1, 3]], axis=1) to drop the columns but don't know where it should go in the code.

Comment: whats your error message ?

Comment: @dermen Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ecorcoran/Desktop/GRB/data/test6.py", line 8, in <module>
    main_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(pd.readcsv(file_list[0], delimiter=r"\s+"))
  File "/Users/ecorcoran/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 261, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'readcsv'

Comment: Ah, indeed, its [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) ... you're missing an underbar. good luck

Comment: Your question is dealing with a lot of individual problems (globbing for files in a folder, concatenating dataframes, etc). most of these have solutions on stack overflow. Id break your problem into as many sub-problems as possible, then search for those individual solutions..

Comment: @dermen thanks and yea i've been trying to search stackoverflow for each different part which is how I arrived at my failed code, but couldn't really piece them all together.